# Push static element between every original element of an array

Tags: php, arrays, interleave

I have a an array like so:

```
$fruit = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana');
```

I would like to combine the array with a separator similar to implode but **without** converting the result to a string.

So instead of

```
implode('.', $fruit); // 'Apple.Orange.Banana'
```

the result should be:

```
array('Apple', '.', 'Orange', '.', 'Banana');
```

This could probably be achieved with loops, however, I am looking for the best possible solution. Maybe there is a native function that can accomplish that which I do not know of? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd probably call this "interleaving" or "alternating" the values, but the description is clear. I don't have an answer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_splice()` with a reversed `for` loop

Remember to remove `1` from `count($fruit)` so we won't add another `.` at the end of the array

```php
<?php

$fruit = [ 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana' ];
for ($i = count($fruit) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    array_splice($fruit, $i, 0, '.');
}

var_dump($fruit);
```

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Apple"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "."
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Orange"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "."
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Banana"
}
```

Comment: @ood thought you wanted to avoid loops :)

Comment: You could avoid loops by making a 2d array and flatten it afterwards, but IMHO this seems the most straight forward way.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are right. However, I guess there is no native function/one-liner that does this, so if loops are the best solution that is fine with me.

Comment: Earlier posted and more dynamic version of this answer can be found at [Push static value into another array at every nth position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73576397/2943403)

Answer (score 3):

You can implode based on `|.|`(period character surrounded by pipes) and then explode on the `|` pipe character.

```
<?php

$fruits = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana');

$d = explode("|", implode('|.|', $fruits));

print_r($d);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yhfzeufp)

**Update:**

As @RiggsFolly mentioned in the comments, you can use a very unlikely character like `chr(1)` as a delimiter.

```
<?php
$fruits = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana');
$sep = chr(1);
$d = explode($sep, implode($sep.'.'.$sep, $fruits));

print_r($d);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yhg22f42)

Comment: I thought about that. The problem is that if a string in the array contains the delimiter (e.g. 'Or|ange') this would not work.

Comment: @Ood You can change the delimiter. `|` is just an option. Also, adding new constraints when an answer is given is not really appreciable.

Comment: Create a Really Really unlikely char as a seperator like `$sep = chr(1);`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I tried to make the question as easy to understand as possible, but of course this should work on any array of strings.

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/php/3yhg22f42 No loop in site, totally ripped off from @nice_dev answer of course

Comment: @RiggsFolly Heeding your advice.

Comment: @Ood Fair enough, but the conditions need to mentioned for us to consider it. Never mind.

Comment: @nic I have hammered this duplicate page.  You may like to add your approach as an answer on the dupe target.  Although, I don't personally like this technique because it requires the developer to be 100% certain that the array values never contain the nominated separator.

Comment: @mickmackusa Since OP didn't mention about the domain of characters, I went with the benefit of doubt.

Comment: @nice It is a working answer -- no shame in that.

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative

Leaning on the `array_*` functions, you could consider the following:

```
function interleave(string $sep, array $arr): array {
  return array_slice(array_merge(...array_map(fn($elem) => [$sep, $elem], $arr)), 1); 
}
```

Due to the use of inbuilt functions and no explicit looping, it exceeds the speed of the looping `array_splice` implementation around the 10 element mark, so the trade-off between terse implementation and performance may be worth it in your case.

#### Explanation

When called like so:

```
interleave('.', ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']);
```

does the following (from the inside out):

##### Map

Map each element to a pair `['.', $elem]`:

```
$mapped = array_map(fn($elem) => ['.', $elem], ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']);
```

resulting in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => .
            [1] => Apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => .
            [1] => Orange
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => .
            [1] => Banana
        )

)
```

##### Merge

Flatten the array using `array_merge` taking advantage of the fact that, from the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> If [...] the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

```
$merged = array_merge(...$mapped);
```

resulting in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => Apple
    [2] => .
    [3] => Orange
    [4] => .
    [5] => Banana
)
```

##### Slice

Slice off the first extra separator:

```
$sliced = array_slice($merged, 1);
```

resulting in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => .
    [2] => Orange
    [3] => .
    [4] => Banana
)
```